# python search for file extension in csv, return full string

Tags: regex, string

I have a csv of file names, and I want to search through the file and return only file names with the .tif extension. I thought maybe I had to write a regular expression, but I couldn't figure that out either. I know this is a simple question, but I'm new at python and could really use some basic help. Thank you!

```
    import csv
    import re

    with open('all_file_names.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    #a = re.compile('tif')
    #b = a.search(reader)
    #findall()

           for row in reader:
                   str.find(".tif") in reader
                   print(row)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a few lines of the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('all_file_names.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '.tif' in line:
            print(line)
```

This assumes that every line only has one filename. you could also do:

```
if line.endswith('.tif'):
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I knew it had to be a simple answer, and I was complicating it. Thank you so much!